# Copy over range iteratively from a single file and paste in new file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file with 10023 lines. I would like to copy every 1000 lines from the file and paste it over to new file which can be named as 1.txt and 2.txt and so on. I want to move the files 1.txt 2.txt and so on into newly created folders 1, 2 etc.

Can someone please help me in this regard.

Thank you

Comment: Are you familiar with the [split](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) command?

Comment: I have not really used the command. I have previously done copying over range using sed command, non-iteratively. But  I am looking at the split command you have given here.

Comment: Why name the files AND directories 1, 2, etc.? Consider naming the files some common string, maybe the same name as the original file, since each file will be in a separate directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `itertools` module method `islice` we chunk out the input file handle iterator and then save the files into the desired directories, creating them on the way.

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys, pathlib, itertools
ifile,chunk_size = sys.argv[1:]
with open(ifile) as fh:
  for i,chunk in enumerate(iter(lambda:list(itertools.islice(fh,int(chunk_size))),[])):
    filepath = pathlib.Path(f"{i}/{i}.txt") 
    filepath.parent.mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)
    with filepath.open("w") as f:
      f.writelines(chunk)
' file 1000
$ tree -F
```

Output:

```
.
├── 1/
│   └── 1.txt
├── 10/
│   └── 10.txt
├── 11/
│   └── 11.txt
├── 2/
│   └── 2.txt
├── 3/
│   └── 3.txt
├── 4/
│   └── 4.txt
├── 5/
│   └── 5.txt
├── 6/
│   └── 6.txt
├── 7/
│   └── 7.txt
├── 8/
│   └── 8.txt
├── 9/
│   └── 9.txt
├── file
```

Answer (score 13):

This is what `split` is for. To split the file into multiple files with 1000 lines (or less, for the last one), you can do:

```
split -d -l 1000 file ''
```

That will split the file into files of 1000 lines each (`-l 1000`), with numerical suffixes with `.txt` as an additional suffix and using an empty prefix (`''`). The result for a file with 10023 lines will be 11 files named `00`, `01`, ..., `10`:

```
$ wc -l file
10023 file
$ split -d -l 1000 --additional-suffix='.txt' file ''
$ ls
00.txt  02.txt  04.txt  06.txt  08.txt  10.txt
01.txt  03.txt  05.txt  07.txt  09.txt  file
```

Note that the `-d` and `--additional-suffix` are not portable and might not be available for your implementation of `split`. They are available for GNU `split` which is the default on Linux systems.

You can now move your files as desired:

```
for i in {00..10}; do
    mkdir -p $i
    mv "$i".txt "$i"/
done
```

And, if you don't want the leading 0s, you can rename them:

```
for i in {00..10}; do
    mkdir -p $i
    mv "$i".txt "$i"/"${i##0}".txt
done
```

Finally, if you want to start from 1 and not from 0, again assuming GNU `split`, you can do:

```
split -d --numeric-suffixes=1 -l 1000 --additional-suffix='.txt' file ''
```

Which will produce:

```
01.txt  03.txt  05.txt  07.txt  09.txt  11.txt
02.txt  04.txt  06.txt  08.txt  10.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd do something like this (untested), assuming your input file name is `Chrom`:

```
awk '
(NR % 1000) == 1 {
    close(out)
    if ( system("mkdir -p \047" (++cnt) "\047") != 0 ) {
        print "Failed to create directory " cnt |"cat>&2"
        exit 1
    }
    out = cnt "/" FILENAME
}
{ print > out }
' Chrom
```

which will create output directories/files like:

```
1/Chrom   2/Chrom   3/Chrom   etc.
```

If you REALLY wanted both the directory names and the file names to be unique it's a trivial tweak to do that (change `FILENAME` to `cnt ".txt"`) but that just seems redundant.

Comment: Thank you @Ed Morton. I managed to get it right this time. Really appreciate your help.